# DateTime.ToString() not converting time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, type-conversion

Looks like time is automatically getting changed during conversion.
My input is `17:15:25`. However, it gets converted to `13:15:25`
What could be the reason?

```
string testDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-03-24T17:15:25.879Z")
                         .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The result I get for `testDate` is : `24-Mar-2016 13:15:25`

Comment: Have you checked if the resulting DateTime is correct? The value of Convert.ToDateTime("2016-03-24T17:15:25.879Z")? If that is incorrect, it is because of your current locale settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Z` in your input indicates a UTC time, but the default behaviour of `Convert.ToDateTime` is to convert the result to your local time. If you look at the result of `Convert.ToDateTime("2016-03-30T17:15:25.879Z").Kind` you'll see it's `Local`.

I would suggest using `DateTime.ParseExact`, where you can specify the *exact* behaviour you want, e.g. preserving the UTC time:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "2016-03-30T17:15:25.879Z",
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);      // March 30 2016 17:15 (...)
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Kind); // Utc
```

You can then convert that value to a string however you want to.

Of course I'd *really* suggest using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project instead, where you'd parse to either an `Instant` or a `ZonedDateTime` which would know it's in UTC... IMO, [`DateTime` is simply broken](http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), precisely due to the kind of problems you've been seeing.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `Convert.ToDateTime` (which uses `DateTime.Parse` internally) with `Z` (which means [Zulu time](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/timezone.htm)), this method adds your current time zone offset to that DateTime value.

Looks like your current time zone is UTC -04:00 right now and that's why method returns 4 hours back as a result.

I would suggest to use `DateTime.ParseExact` with `AdjustToUniversal` and `AssumeUniversal` styles for prevent [`Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind) conversion as [Jon answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358142/447156).

From [`AdjustToUniversal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Date and time are returned as a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). If
>   the input string denotes a local time, through a time zone specifier
>   or `AssumeLocal`, the date and time are converted from the local time to
>   UTC. **If the input string denotes a UTC time, through a time zone
>   specifier or `AssumeUniversal`, no conversion occurs**. If the input
>   string does not denote a local or UTC time, no conversion occurs and
>   the resulting `Kind` property is `Unspecified`.

Comment: I believe what you mean is UTC -04:00

Comment: @Ian Ups, fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, no problem. Nice answer. :)

Comment: @Soner, Thank you, that fixed it.

Comment: @Richard Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.
You are converting a date in your GMT

```
Convert.ToDateTime("2016-03-24T17:15:25.879Z")
```

And then you are converting it to string in an invariant culture

```
ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should use DateTime.ParseExact, and then use the invariant culture in the conversion.